# Conda defined environment variable not seen by program

Tags: python, conda

I have a python project with the following structure:

[image: directory structure]

In `conda.yml` I have defined some environment variables as follows:

```
name: terraform_module_overview
dependencies:
  - pip
  - pip:
      - stashy
      - oauthlib
      - requests_oauthlib
variables:
  - BB_USER=someUser
```

And in the python program `python/terraformModuleMarkdownGenerator.py`, I try to read the environment variable as follows:

```
import os

print(os.getenv("BB_USER")
```

Then when I try to execute it using the conda environment, with these commands on root of the project:

```
conda env create --file conda.yml && \
  conda run -n terraform_module_overview python/terraformModuleMarkdownGenerator.py
```

It install successfully the dependencies:

> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
>
> Solving environment: ...working... done
>
> Installing pip dependencies: ...working... done

... but on the execution it fails:

> ERROR conda.cli.main_run:execute(33): Subprocess for 'conda run
> ['python/terraformModuleMarkdownGenerator.py']' command failed.  (See
> above for error)
>
> None
>
> ERROR: BB_USER is undefined in the Environment

What I am missing here?

Comment: Does it get defined when manually activating? E.g., `conda activate terraform_module_overview && echo "$BB_USER"`. Also, what's your Conda version?

Comment: It activates the env successfully (as it changes the prompt of the terminal) but the echo returns null. My conda version is 4.9.2

Comment: yep, I miss to reply, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the incorrect syntax for defining variables ([see documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#setting-environment-variables)). Instead, try

**conda.yml**

```yaml
name: terraform_module_overview
dependencies:
  - pip
  - pip:
    - stashy
    - oauthlib
    - requests_oauthlib
variables:
  BB_USER: someUser
```